# Connect to a specific country using Psiphon vpn from Command line

Tags: cmd, automation, ip, open-source, vpn

I'm currently working on a project where I need to connect to different countries using Psiphon vpn each time inorder to proceed with my automation.

Is it possible to connect to country of my choice from the cmd line using psiphon vpn?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"EgressRegion": "XX"` to the configuration file, where `XX` is a two-digit country code.

`"EgressRegion": "DE"`